# How to write regex to extract lines from below stack

Tags: regex

How to write regex to extract lines from below stack

I am new to regex and want to extract lines from below stack. Below are the rules

1. After exception extract the first line which starts with 'at'
2. Get the first line which starts with at com.test(This line optional may or may not be present in the whole file)
3. Get the line which starts with at com.test and not similar to step 2 com. test line package(This line optional may or may not be present in the whole file)

Partially tried with lookahead but no result.

`(Exception).*[\n\r]*.*at\s+(((?<pack>.*)(.*\.(?<packfunc>.*\..*)\())).*((?<Offset>:\d+))\)(((?=(\n.*)*at\s+((?<pack1>(com.test.*))(.*\.(?<packfunc1>(.*\..*)))[\(]).*(?<ffset1>:\d+)\))|))`

Input

IllegalArgumentException

```
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at com.test.package1.user1.client1.client1.Call.invoke(Call.java:90)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at com.test.package1.user1.client1.client1.Call.invoke(SrvCall.java:84)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.test.package2.user2.client2.client2.Call.invoke(Call.java:90)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
```

Expected Result
1.org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)

2.com.test.package1.user.client.client1.Call.invoke(Call.java:90)

3.com.test.package2.user2.client2.client2.Call.invoke(Call.java:90)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
IllegalArgumentException\n\s*at\s+(.+)(?:(?:\n\s*at(?!\s*com\.test).*)*(?:\n\s*at\s+((com\.test[^(\n]*).*)(?:\n\s*at.*)*\n\s*at\s+(?!\3)(com\.test.*))?)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQ69Wr/2/)

**Details**

- `IllegalArgumentException`  - a string
- `\n\s*` - newline and 0+ whitespaces
- `at\s+` - `at` and 1+ whitespaces
- `(.+)` - Group 1: the first `at` line
- `(?:\n\s*at(?!\s*com\.test).*)*` - lines starting with indented `at` that have no `test.com` after `at`
- `\n\s*at\s+` - a line starting with indented `at` and 1+ whitespaces
- `((com\.test[^(\n]*).*)` - Group 2: the `com.test` line with the part before `(` 
  captured into Group 3
- `(?:\n\s*at.*)*` - 0 or more lines starting with `at`
- `\n\s*at\s+(?!\3)` - linebreak, 1+ spaces, `at`, 1+ whitespaces and there can be no text as in Group 3 right after
- `(com\.test.*)` - Group 4: `com.test` and the rest of the line.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This regex should work even if there is no com. test lines in the log files. But above regex is not working if you remove com. test lines from the log file.

Comment: @intu Make the whole parts optional. See https://regex101.com/r/hQ69Wr/2

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hQ69Wr/3 in this second match would be this line com.test.package3.user3.client3.client3.Call.invoke(Call.java:90) but is going till end and finding this com.test.package2.user2.client2.client2.Call.invoke(Call.java:90)

Comment: @intu Make it lazy, https://regex101.com/r/hQ69Wr/4. These details are missing from your question. You are free to adjust the pattern by yourself, making parts of it non-greedy if you need the leftmost matches.

Comment: ..This is what I was expected..you saved my whole day.Thanks